# How to link multiple tables in Joomla 2.5 Component?

Tags: model-view-controller, joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-component

I am trying to create a component which uses 3 tables in the database. I want to link the first table with the second one, then second with third.

To be more precise, consider this :

1. Category: **id**, **name**
2. Sub category: **id**, **category_id**, **name**
3. Sub sub category: **id**, **subcategory_id**, **name**

I have created models, controllers and views for all the three tables. Just want to know how to link them together so that on the list view of Categories, I can have a link for subcategories and on clicking on that link, I can show the subcategories for the category.

I have googled this for almost 3 days now. But can't find an answer.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'd suggest you to use native Joomla categories. More info can be found here: http://tormix.com/joomla/how-to-use-jcategories-in-my-component.html

Comment: I just used categories for example. Its actually 3 different tables.

Comment: If you're using Joomla 1.6 or newer you don't need to create any tables, all your categories are stored in #__categories table. That saves alot of time and work in editing and listing categories.

Comment: Ohh.. may be I am not clear. Actually, I want to create Courses, chapters and then tests. So each course will have chapters, each chapter will have tests etc.. I used categories just for the example.

Comment: Just taking a stab here, but have you tried setting your engine type for these tabes as innodb and using foreign keys for relationships? the you would use joins in you mysql query.